# CodeIgniter: Multiple Applications, how to set $application_folder?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm planning to follow Method 2 as described here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Multiple-Applications, which will result in my folder structure being:

```
/application/
    /frontend/
    /backend/
/system/
```

The wiki further states that,

> "Both frontend.php & backend.php are
>   duplicate of the index.php, where
>   you’ll need to update the
>   `$application_folder` in each file
>   pointed to the corresponding folder"

My question: in the given example, what exactly should the values of `$application_folder` be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't changed anything big in the index.php file, the default is by line 43.

The default is "application",

I think that in your case it's "frontend" & "backend"

Comment: It was `application/frontend`. Thanks.